# In java, can nested class object use the enclosing class method?

Tags: java, static, inner-classes

I created a simple list class. What I want to do is to create a method in SLList to give the size a SLList object. I want to do it recursively, however, the following size() method I created just does not work. I know other ways to realize it such as creating a helper method. But what I am curious about is that why does my size() does not work? The error message is the "size() is undefined for SLList.IntNode". Why? Since I made the nested IntMode class just public and non-static, why it cannot use the method that is defined in SLList class?

```
public class SLList {

    public class IntNode {

        public int item;
        public IntNode next;

        public IntNode(int i, IntNode n) {
            item = i;
            next = n;
        }
    }

    private IntNode first;

    public SLList(int x) {
        first = new IntNode(x, null);
    }

    public int size() {
        if (first.next == null) {
           return 1;
        }
        return 1 + first.next.size();
    }
}
```

I am just new to Java, and quite confused about the private and static things, especially when it comes to the Class. Thank you for anyone answering me.

Comment: have you tried? In your code, how would it make sense to do so?

Comment: `IntNode` has no method called `size()`. And right now there is no recursion at all. You should google for `singly linked list`

Comment: @Stultuske sorry, I made some indentation mistakes on the above code. Now I corrected it. but the key problem of mine is that can IntNode variable or object use the method defined in SLLlist?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Do you mean that the first.next actually needs to use the method defined in IntNode? Here the size() is not defined in IntNode, so it cannot use it, right? So, does that mean the nested Class cannot use the outer Class's method?

Comment: @zangsy again: how would that make any sense?

Comment: Yes, it could  use a method of `SLList`, but only by invoking that method on some instance of `SLList`.  `IntList` can't "hijack" the outer class's method to use on an `IntList` instance.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Oh! I got it. Since "first" is an IntNode instance, not the SLList's, so it cannot use the method defined in SLList.

Comment: Exactly.  It's really no different than would have been the case had `IntList` been an entirely separate class rather than having been nested within `SLList`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fiddle it by adding an extra private method but it's not particularly easy to reason about. I would avoid doing it this way unless absolutely necessary.

```
class SLList {

    public class IntNode {

        public int item;
        public IntNode next;

        public IntNode(int i, IntNode n) {
            item = i;
            next = n;
        }

        private int theSize()
        {
            return size();
        }
    }

    private IntNode first;

    public SLList(int x) {
        first = new IntNode(x, null);
    }

    public int size() {
        if (first.next == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 1 + first.next.theSize();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason is : your method **`size()`** is in class **SLList**.

Hence it cannot be accessed by `nested inner class` `IntNode`.

Answer (score 0):

`size()` is a method of `SLList`, not `IntNode`. You can refer to outer class method inside `IntNode` as follows:

```
public class SLList {

    public class IntNode {
        ...

        public int size() {
            return SLList.this.size();
        }
    }

    ...

    public static int size() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a size method to IntNode class and access it from SLList size method to calculate the entire size of the list. The following code snippet is self explanatory. For more information about nested classes refer https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/nested-inner-class

```
public class SLList {

    public class IntNode {

        public int item;
        public IntNode next;

        public IntNode(int i, IntNode n) {
            item = i;
            next = n;
        }

        public int size() {
            IntNode tmp = next;

            if (tmp == null) {
                return 1;
            }

            return 1 + tmp.size();
        }
    }

    private IntNode first;

    public SLList(int x) {
        first = new IntNode(x, null);
    }

    public int size() {
        if (first == null)
            return 0;
        return first.size();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SLList list = new SLList(10);
        list.first.next = list.new IntNode(20, null);
        list.first.next.next = list.new IntNode(30, null);
        list.first.next.next.next = list.new IntNode(40, null);

        System.out.println(list.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is because the size() method definition is outside of IntNode. The definition for size() is missing in class IntNode.

In addition about doing recursive method, the recursive implementation normally have entry method and the recursive. Your implementation missing the recursive method.

```
// entry
public int size() {
   if (first == null) {
      return 0;
   }
   return 1 + nodeSize( first.next );
}

// recursive - private, only called from size()
private int nodeSize( IntNode node) {
   if (node == null) {
      return 0;
   }
   return 1 + nodeSize( node.next );
}
```